# Об этимологии глаголов «выразить» и «заразить»

Tags: этимология

Я пишу диссертацию о понятии заразительности у Толстого и хотел бы выяснить этимологию этого термина. Моя гипотеза заключается в том, что в контексте XIX века русского языка люди видели эти термины как однокоренные, и это сходство, возможно, было значительным для Толстого.

Я искал происхождение этих слов и нашел глагол «разить» в значении «бить».

Но я заметил, что в других славянских языках глагол «разить» дал слова, у которых значение близко к значениям глаголов «срезать» или «начертать».

Первый вопрос следующий: чувствуют ли русские такие смысл и коннотации в глаголах «выразить» и «заразить»?

Я также подумал, что глагол «выразить» на самом деле мог бы быть калькой латинского глагола «ex-primo». Как вам кажется?

Спасибо!

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97689/discussion-on-question-by-user21102------).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока только часть ответа:

Гипотезу о том, что "выражать/выразить" есть калька латинского *exprimere* разделяет как минимум ещё [один человек](https://www.quicksilvertranslate.com/2702/express-etymology).

К сожалению, в этой статье он не объясняет, на каком основании он это утверждает, но интуитивно (а также зная другие подобные примеры) хочется с ним согласиться. Но соглашаться тут нужно осторожно, так как есть важный нюанс: сам глагол *выражати* - исконно русский, его **точное** значение (или, скорее, область применения), скажем, в допушкинский период я объяснить не возьмусь - нужно изучать старинные тексты. Судя по всему, глагол был переосмыслен в 19-м веке для выражения того, что во французском передавалось словом *expression*, и в этом узком смысле его можно назвать калькой.

**Продолжение:**

Попробую прокомментировать вот эти абзацы:

> Моя гипотеза заключается в том, что в контексте XIX века русского
>   языка люди видели эти термины как однокоренные, и это сходство,
>   возможно, было значительным для Толстого.
>
> Но я заметил, что в других славянских языках глагол «разить» дал
>   слова, у которых значение близко к значениям глаголов «срезать» или
>   «начертать». Первый вопрос следующий: чувствуют ли русские такие смысл
>   и коннотации в глаголах «выразить» и «заразить»?

*В уже удаленном чате у нас был с одним из участником некий микро-спор, но по сути я сейчас скажу примерно то же самое, что сказал и он (это связано с тем, что "он": во-первых, отвечал на оригинальный, английский вариант вопроса, а во-вторых, немного поторопился и выразил мысль не совсем удачно по форме).*

Тут у вас некий разброс терминов. То, что эти слова `однокоренные`, достаточно очевидно для русскоговорящего что в XIX, что в XXI веке. По крайней мере, для человека, который не прогуливал уроки русского языка в школе.

Но вот по поводу `чувствовать смысл и коннотации` с глаголом "разить" и, тем более, "резать" - такого нет. И думаю, что такие коннотации не ощущались и во времена Толстого (надеюсь, что эта гипотеза не является краеугольным камнем вашей диссертации).

То есть, в современном русском никакой семантической связи `выразить / заразить` с `разить`, на мой взгляд, носителем языка не чувствуется, по крайней мере, до тех пор пока ему её не объяснят. :) Другое дело - `сразить / поразить` (которые достаточно редко употребляются в прямом значении, все больше в переносном), здесь смысловая связь с `разить` достаточно прозрачна. Опять же `сражение / поражение` в этом хорошо помогают.

Мне показалось, что английский тоже не ваш родной язык, тем не менее приходит на ум такое сравнение, как [`get`](https://www.etymonline.com/word/get) и [`forget`](https://www.etymonline.com/word/forget). Думаю, что современные англоговорящие так же ясно видят, что эти слова `однокоренные`, но не думаю, что они ощущают изначальную семантическую связь (впрочем, тут я могу ошибаться, надо спрашивать у носителей).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По моему его гипотеза, что слово «выражать» образовалось через немецкий ausdrücken намного вероятнее с исторической точки зрения. Только я не могу понять почему drücken => разить. Мне кажется, что drücken => давить - очевиднее.

Comment: Я не думаю, что это **его** гипотеза. Судя по тексту, автор статьи скорее журналист/блоггер, нежели лингвист. И потом, там не говорится, что "образовалось через немецкий", это вы невнимательно прочитали.

Comment: Тоже так считаю. Я просто имел ввиду, что эта идея убедительнее той, которую предлагал.

Comment: То, что Вы добавили про существование исконно русского глагола «выражати» и его переосмысление в XIX-ом веке - очень важно, спасибо ! Я нашёл в словари Аникина, что «выражати» значило «выбить» или «разрушать». Потом написано : «современное значение развивается с начала до середины XVIII-ого под влиянием славянизмов «изразить»». Там тоже утверждают гипотезу, что переосмысление слова развивалось под влиянием немецкого ausdrücken и латинского exprimere. Так, я считаю эту часть вопроса - решена. Спасибо!

Comment: @user21102 Вместо "спасибо" здесь принято щёлкнуть по "стрелке вверх" слева от ответа.

Comment: Да я хотел, но поскольку у меня нет 15 баллов, это не было вошёл в счёт.

Comment: @tum_ 11 Не удержался от комментария про английскую пару слов. Мне кажется, что даже я ощущаю некую семантическую связь между ними. `get` - получить, `forget` - потерять (из памяти). То есть противоположности. Вот почему именно `for` - не понятно.

Comment: @oleedd Почему именно *for* довольно легко найти в интернете. Кстати, можно будет все-таки спросить на en.SE у native speakers насколько ими "ощущается" смысл этой словообразующей приставки. А скорее всего это уже спрашивалось, и надо лишь поискать ответы. Да, на свежую голову мне тоже кажется, что пример неудачен.

Answer (score 0):

Я попробую дать ответы на вопросы по этимологии. Что касается Толстого и использования им слов в необычном значении - это тема совершенно неподъемная в рамкам формата ресурса. Уж во всяком случае диссертацию вам тут не напишут.

**Заражать** - от зараза (а может быть, и наоборот, не принципиально). Исторический корень тут действительно "раз/раж" - чередование "з"/"ж" объясняется историческими фонетическими процессами. Само же "разить" восходит к "резать" - и изначально сохранило часть значений последнего.
Таким образом, зараза - это то, что режет, поражает. В данном случае развилось переносное значение, ибо "зараза" поражает без какого-либо акта резания. 
А "заражать", "заразительность" - это уже дальнейшее перенесение значения на действие, которое заражает не болезнью, но чувствами.

На этом историко-языковом фоне "выражать" (показать, обнаружить, передать, воплотить в каком-либо внешнем проявлении) не выглядит какой-то калькой. Фактически это понятие весьма близко к заражать в рассмотренном переносном значении. Разница в том, что "выражать" - это само действие по передаче своих чувств, мыслей, а "заражать" - то же действие, направленное на конкретный объект.

(Надеюсь, перевод не нужен.)

> Я искал происхождение этих слов и нашел глагол «разить» в значении
>   «бить».

Дело все в том, что  "бить" само по себе многозначно и претерпело многочисленные исторические семантические изменения. Здесь "бить" = "резать", а "резать"  в значении "причинять вред с помощью холодного оружия".

Comment: Мне кажется: "а может быть, и наоборот" — вводное слово, а "хотя может быть и наоборот" — член предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Есть источники ?

Comment: Что касается слияния значении «бить» и «резать», у меня такое же впечатление, но у меня нет источников для поддержки этой идеи.

Comment: @user21102 *Есть источники* - Фасмер. Статьи "Заражать",  "выражать" и прочие. А каких источников тут ещё надобно? Толстого я не комментирую.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой *Мне кажется: "а может быть, и наоборот"*  - Я принимаю вариант с запятой. Честно говоря, не успел еще даже проверить - и задуматься.

Comment: @user21102 *Что касается слияния значении «бить» и «резать», у меня такое же впечатление, но у меня нет источников для поддержки этой идеи.* - Ну ві просто сравните семантические поля этих двух слов - по тому же Фасмеру. Какого-то серьезного анализа тут и не требуется.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой `@behemothus` Там было правильно, запятую нельзя. Быть как? наоборот. Но: а может быть и, наоборот, вниз. Но "и" тут никак не может примыкать к вводному слову.

Comment: @oleedd не ерундите. Оба варианта возможны "может быть" как  вводное никто не отменял.

Comment: Oleedd, ну что вы говорите!) "Наоборот" здесь не вводное слово, а наречие.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой если можно, не вступайте в полемику с этим экземпляром под моим ответом. Просто модератор убьет все обсуждение - и будет прав, ибо какой-то театр абсурда. А вот с топикстартером мы, надеюсь, сможем как-то найти общий язык по существу.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Если "может быть" было было вводным, то было бы: или, может быть, наоборот. "а" к вводному "может быть" примыкать не может. Источник: http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=1029

Comment: Спасибо behemothus и Артёму Луговому за вашу разумность. Я прочёл статьи про слова «раз» и «зараза» в словари Фасмера (в интернете, я сейчас на работе). Там говорится, что слова « резать » и « разить » связаны, но не говорится чем. А то, что ищу - именно объяснение этой связи, мотивацию деривации. Я знаю, что мой вопрос не совсем ортодоксальный, поскольку можно только предложить гипотезы, объясняющие эту связь. Я просто думал, что возможно учёные, к которым можно относиться, уже предложили такие гипотезы. Если таких гипотез нет, то одобрю ответ behemothus.

Comment: *Там говорится, что слова « резать » и « разить » связаны, но не говорится чем.* - так они из одного слова происходят. Это два деривата одного праславянского слова. Фонетическая вариация постепенно привела к возникновению двух разных значений. Это обычная ситуация в русском языке, если вы  у Фасмера или где-то еще найдете два чем-то похожих слова без объяснения их связи, речь всегда идет о чем-то  подобном.

Comment: Примером, «восходить» - дериват слова «ходить» по приложению префикса «вос»/«вз», который обычно (не всегда) выражает идею «чего-то, которое идёт наверх» (взлетать, например). Так, что в этом примере фонематическая деривация соответствует значению второго глагола. Можно не только описать, но и объяснить это словообразование. Теперь, сто касается дериваций «разить» => «заразить» или «разить» =>  «выразить», я бы хотел понять, не только фонематическое явление, но какая мотивация этого явление, какой смысл деривации. Но, может быть, нет гипотез такого рода, и ученые только описывали эту деривацию

Comment: @user21102 "Там говорится, что слова « резать » и « разить » связаны, но не говорится чем. - так они из одного слова происходят. Это два деривата одного праславянского слова." - хочется подчеркнуть, что процесс разделения этих двух корней судя по всему произошел за много веков до выделения (древне-)русского языка в отдельный язык. То есть, к Толстому это уж совсем не имеет отношения.

Answer (score 0):

Связь между этими словами довольно сложно естественно ощутить даже тем, кто разбирается в русском языке. Уж слишком разный семантический вектор между ними. Причина также в том, что "заразительно" воспринимается негативно без позитивного контекста. Но именно в контексте искусства это слово часто употребляется в позитивном аспекте.

Но после длительного аналитического процесса удалось выявить явную связь между данными словами. Чтобы выявить этимологические закономерности между двумя понятиями, лучше использовать переходы. Понять эту связь очень помогает прилагательное "выразительный".

`Выразительный` - в прямом смысле слова означает бьющий!, как фонтан, искрящийся, удивляющий (перен. к "бить") своими чувствами, переживаниями, эмоциями, художественной составляющей.

Скорее всего, слово "выражать" образовалось как действие по отношению к данной характеристике (делать выразительным).

Это скрытое сходство со словом "бить". Но бывает и прямое сходство:

`Я тебе сейчас выражу всё, что я о тебе думаю.` (побью морально)

`Заразительность` - способность передаваться (распространятся на другого) как следствие сильной выразительности.

`Выразительность` - важнейшая аспект формирования искусства (зарождение), а `заразительность` - влияние на других (результат).

То есть `выразительность` - это внутренний фактор, а `заразительность` - внешний.

Вряд ли такие скрытые связи были очевидны обычным людям даже тогда. Но Толстой как очень умный и грамотный человек и особенно как автор данной концепции вполне мог осознавать существование и значимость этих связей.

Скорее всего, связь между этими понятиями была не просто значимой для Толстого - а колоссально важной. Более того, возможно, основой для его концепции. Причиной этому является следующая простая закономерность:

`Чем больше выразительности - тем сильнее заразительность.`

Суть выражается в следующем:

Чем больше художник (любого искусства) вкладывает (от семя самого) в своё произведение - тем более оно заразительно. И тем большую популярность оно снискает у общества.

Русская поговорка на этот счёт:

`Что посеешь - то и пожнёшь.`

После осознания этих связей начинает казаться, что концепция Толстого в какой-то мере гениальна.

От себя добавлю, что тема данной диссертации действительно очень интересна для исследования.

Вывод: гипотеза очень логична и диссертация будет защищена. Точка.

Comment: @tum_ Всё-таки удалось ощутить эту связь.

Comment: @user21102 `Выразить` = разить изнутри. Приставка `вы` используется в словах для обозначения действия изнутри наружу. `Заразить` = разить другого. Приставка `за`обозначает передачу действия. Только сейчас понял. Нужно было анализировать морфемы.